# Auto orderlist Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm using Excel 2010 to create a inventory of my shop.

Now I would like it to automatically create a order list in the second sheet.

My first sheet look like this.

```
Item:   Stock:  Min.    Max.
Apple   17      15      30
```

So, I'm looking for a way to get this an my second sheet

```
Item:   Order:
Apple   13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to approach this is to use Excel's built-in Table and Pivot Table features.

1. Convert your existing inventory into a Table.
2. Add a column for Reorder quantity, e.g. `=IF([Stock]<[Min],[Max]-[Stock],0)`

   **EDIT:**  Here's what the progression to create your Table from Text looks like:

   [image: reorder progress]
3. On a second worksheet insert a Pivot Table based upon your inventory Table.
4. Setup the Pivot Table with:

   - Row Labels = Item
   - Values = sum of Reorder
   - Filter = Reorder <> 0 (just clear the 0 check box)

[image: Reorder]

As you update your inventory Table, refresh your Pivot Table and it will show you all the items that have a reorder quantity greater than 0.

Comment: In wich cell do i place the IF statement?

Comment: After you create the table with your existing data, go to the next column and add Reorder (in the header/dark blue row).  Then add the =IF statement in the cell below the new label.  Excel will then automatically add that formula to all the cells in that column.

Comment: I followed all your steps but I am still stuck at the part were I enter the =IF statement. When I enter the forumula something strange happens, because after the first comma Excel won't colour the other columnnames in the forumula. When I continue to just enter the rest it highlights "[Min],[Max]" after I'm done and says that there is a error in the formula.

Comment: Instead of typing the names, try navigating with the arrow keys. So type =if( then use the arrow keys to select the values to calculate. Once you've selected the value enter your operator or comma as appropriate. See if that helps and let me know...

Comment: I get a error when i try to enter the "Max" column after the first comma. There seems to be something wrong with the formula. Is there a way to make the formula work without the comma?

Comment: The comma is required to separate the function's arguments. Did you enclose Min and Max in brackets, like this [Max]? Since Max is the name of an Excel function, it may be getting confused. If its still not working, please paste the entire string in a comment, along with the exact error type.

Comment: Finaly, i had to change the comma for a semicolon now it works, thanks!

Comment: Great to hear, I'm glad you were able to get it working.  Sorry I didn't think of that-I believe that's a setting that is controlled in the Regional Settings area of Windows where you can modify the decimal and list separator characters, but I've never had to deal with it.

Comment: That could be it, im using a Dutch version of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming a couple of things here. In Sheet 1 A2 is the location of the first item (Apple in this case). You can do this on Sheet 2 in the A column:

```
Item
=Sheet1!A2
```

Assuming that order is Max - Stock you can have this in the B column:

```
Order
=Sheet1!D2-Sheet1!B2
```

Might be easier just to do it all on one sheet but I think the above answers your question.